# Distribution of the power of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> Three students are working independently on their probability homework. They start at the same time. The times that they take to finish it are i.i.d. random variables $T_1$, $T_2$ , $T_3$ with $T_j^{1/\beta} \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$, where β and λ are known positive constants.
>
> Find the PDF of $T_1$

I simplify the notation by solving the equivalent problem: Let $X \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$, and $Y=X^{\beta}$, find the PDF of $Y$.

by the change of variables formula,

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= f_X(g^{-1}(y)) * \lvert \frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} \rvert \\
&=\lambda e^{-\lambda y^{1/\beta}}  \frac{y^{\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}}}{\beta} 
\quad y \geq0
\end{align}

Is this correct? I somehow could not find it to be true by using simulation.

Comment: Replace $e^{\lambda y^{1/\beta}}$ by $e^{-\lambda y^{1/\beta}}$ in $f_Y(y)$ and everything will be fine.

Comment: @Did That was actually just a typo when writing it in MathTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks OK to me, and I derived it using the cumulative distribution method, so more or less independently of the change of variables formula. Also when I put $\lambda=1$ and $\beta=1/3$ and simulate this I get reasonably good agreement between the empirical distribution and the form for the density.

[image: Histogram and pdf derives frequency polygon]
*Histogram of Simulated Data and pdf Derived Frequency Polygon*

Comment: Thank's for the verification!